# Font type in <c:out> tag in JSP

Tags: css, spring, jsp

In my spring jsp page i have c:out
tag. I want to set font-family:Arial for this c:out content. Is there any way to do this.

I tried

```
<font style="font-family:Arial">
 <c:out>
</font>
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div style="font-family: arial">
```

the <font> tag is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Curious. I assume that the Arial is installed on your system and available to the browser. Forgive me if this sounds stupid, but are you sure it's not working? Many fonts can look similar if the size is sufficiently small. Try increasing the font-size and check again, just to be certain (style="font-family: arial; font-size: 24px").

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Arial was not working, although it is working in other jsp (not with c:out) but it worked with Courier New font type.

Comment: What, exactly, is your c:out outputting?